# What settings should I use to run Ubuntu in a virtual machine?

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I already have the virtual machine downloaded, and am in the process of downloading Ubuntu along with it, I just do not know what settings I should set to for a fairly weak I5-4250U 4gb RAM ($200 laptop) laptop.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that with Ubuntu in a virtualbox, you'll have 2 systems running in parallel. So you have to split your 4GB RAM for these 2 systems. When you have finished downloading, you configure a virtual machine with 2 GB RAM and a dynamically growing disk, load the .iso file into the virtual CD drive and start the virtual machine.

Comment: I would recommend using Xubuntu if you  need a desktop VM. GNOME ( default ) is somewhat resource intensive, and even with 8 GB RAM on my laptop there is still lag. No lag with XFCE though. Also give the VM as many CPU cores as you can

Answer (score 1):

I run Lubuntu (Ubuntu with LXDE desktop) on a 4gb machine, using a pentium g4400 (2 cores, 3.3 GHz).

- I assigned 1 core out of the available 2.
- 1 GB ram. You can adjust this, if you won't be using other programs on the host, you can add more for the guest, up to around 2-2.5 GB just to be safe.
- 64 MB for graphics. I don't have a dedicated graphics card. If you do, you can be more generous.
- For storage, most people will choose a dynamic disk. However, if your host is low on storage space, then it's better to create a fixed size drive with just the minimum required size (probably around 10-15 GB). For mine I chose a 25 GB fixed size drive, because why not.

This works ok for testing some stuff. I wouldn't render videos or play here.